# Set value of span if input is empty

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate this form and set the value of span if the corresponding input value is empty. However, `.siblings()` and `.next()` are not working.

```js
$('#cf_submit').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  validateForm();
});

function validateForm() {
  if ($('#cf_name').val() || $('#cf_email').val() == '') {

    //$('.calc_error').text('Required'); //THIS WORKS
    $(this).siblings('.calc_error').text('Required'); //doesnt work
    //$(this).parent("div").children('span').text('Required') //doesn't work

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

  <div>
    <label for="cf_name">Name </label>
    <input class="calc_input" type="text" id="cf_name" name="cf_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" size="40" />
    <br>
    <span class="calc_error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="cf_email">Email </label>
    <input class="calc_input" type="email" id="cf_email" name="cf_email" size="40" />
    <br>
    <span class="calc_error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit_button" id="cf_submit" name="cf_submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Does your validateFrom know `this` context? What is the value of `this` when the function is called? You are calling it from the click on submit button but if you try it it will not even be that button. As a solution you could divide the `if` into two ifs: `IF cf_name problem THEN $('#cf_name').siblings('.calc_error').text('Required'); IF cf_email problem THEN $('#cf_email').siblings('.calc_error').text('Required');`

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/vhmja20b/

Comment: Your fiddle has `$('#cf_name').val` instead of `$('#cf_name').val()` (missing brackets) in the if condition on line 7.

Comment: Thank you. That was the answer. Can you please post this as answer so I may accept it?

Comment: Done (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43431814/7081773). Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validateForm` is using "wrong" `this`.

1. It is called from the submit button so at best it should represent that button, not the actual input.
2. In this case, validateForm is called from another function. Therefor it has no idea even about submit `this`. In such case it represents the `window`.

As a solution you could divide the if into two ifs:

`IF cf_name problem THEN $('#cf_name').siblings('.calc_error').text('Required');`

`IF cf_email problem THEN $('#cf_email').siblings('.calc_error').text('Required');`

Answer (score 1):

**.siblings()** working perfectly.But i think css selector is the problem in your case.
That is $(this).siblings indicates window element's siblings.
So try the following code

Jquery

```
$('#cf_submit').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  validateForm();
});

function validateForm() {
  $('.calc_input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).siblings('.calc_error').text('* required');
    } else {    
      $(this).siblings('.calc_error').text('');
    }
  }); 
}
```

CSS

```
span {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/xgtub06c/

Answer (score 0):

The scope of $(this) is the problem. See the attached screenshot with checking the relevant scopes in the console.
[screenshot of console showing relevant objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTKgT.png)

I prepared a CopedPen with the working code. Simply not using $(this).siblings(), but $('.calc_error') to identify the object you want to change.

[Link to Solution on CodePen](https://codepen.io/laszlo-jflmtco/pen/vmOLQW)

```
    // $(this).siblings('.calc_error').text('Required'); //doesnt work
    $('.calc_error').text('Required'); //It works
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems you have misunderstood. Please see my code snippet again. I could get it to work using that code. However, I only want it to show when the corresponding input field is empty.